# Crash when sharing enitre screen in Chrome with Wayland on Dell Laptop with NVIDIA, 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, dell, wayland

I cant get screen sharing to work in chrome (Version 105.0.5195.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on wayland. webrtc pipewire flag is activated.

chrome://gpu tells me that it uses wayland, but chrome isnt showing up in xlsclients. also I cant select the chrome window with xwininfo.

these are the first error when I run google-chrome in terminal:

```
[68336:68336:0926/085840.535938:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl, ANGLE is
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to open i915: ...
```

If I try to share my entire screen in google meet, I give permission, see the "thumbnail" of my entire screen, select it, click share, and chrome crashes with this:

```
[70043:70992:0926/091522.621029:ERROR:egl_dmabuf.cc(569)] Failed to record frame: Error creating EGLImage - EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[70043:70992:0926/091522.621040:ERROR:shared_screencast_stream.cc(665)] Dropping DMA-BUF modifier: 72057594037927935 and trying to renegotiate stream parameters
[0926/091526.775489:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[1] 70043 segmentation fault (core dumped) google-chrome
```

workaround is using xorg instead of wayland. machine is a DELL XPS 15 9560 with gtx 1050. propritary driver 515 is installed and works fine.

appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: Although the latest Nvidia drivers work somewhat well in wayland, it's still considered experimental.